# #ifdef statement to check for testing scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I have added a test target for my project, now I want to separate parts of the code that will not be executed on the app target. Let's say the app called `TestMyApp` and I want it to be something like:

```
-(void)addDevice:(Account*)account{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:K_THINKERBELL_SERVER_URL];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];    


NSDictionary *params = @{@"device_id":account.deviceID,
                         @"token":account.deviceToken ? account.deviceToken : @"fuygciureygfiyuergfyurgfuyergfuyerguy",
                         @"type":account.deviceName,
                         @"os_type":@"ios",
                         @"os_version":account.os,
                         @"accounts":_accounts};


NSString *js = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:params];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:@"/device" parameters:nil];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[js UTF8String] length:[js length]];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
        if ([[JSON objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"success"]) {

***#ifdef TestMyApp
   some code here***
  [self.testDelegate addDeviceJson:JSON type:@"addDevice"];
                                                            [self deviceAdded:[JSON objectForKey:@"uid"]];
                                                            [self.accountsDelegate deviceDidAdded];
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                                                        }];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Target, Preprocessing section. In "Preprocessor macros" you can add defines for any scheme. For example:

```
TESTING=1
```

Then you can write

```
#ifdef TESTING
...
#endif
```

or

```
#if TESTING
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two pch file and add these to each of the target created. Now define some const string and based on that handle the code changes.